# How to filter continous output in terminal

Tags: powershell, shell, terminal, git-bash

Suppose I have following python code

```
import time
def foo():
    print("something " + str(time.ctime()))
    print("whatever " + str(time.ctime()))
    time.sleep(1)
foo()
foo()
```

this should print `something-time` followed by `whatever-time` every second. What I want to do is filter only `something-time` in the terminal output.

what I have tried is

```
python test.py | grep "something"
```

but grep filters after the execution is done.

So is there any way to filter this "live"? (Also I don't have any preference so solution related to any kind of shell is fine.)

Comment: Both programs run simultaneously. You could turn off buffering in Python, so that the line is sent to the pipe immediately.

Comment: Got it. Any idea if I can update that filter in realtime?

Comment: Did you already consider googling for "turn off buffering in Python"?

Comment: Yes. You answered the original question. I was asking that if I can update the "filtering string" while the thing is executing. Maybe topic for another question. Thank you anyways.

Comment: If you ask a new question, make sure that you explain clearly what you are looking for. From your description in the comment, I don't understand what _updating the filtering string_ means, so it might be helpful if you post a concrete example.